# Is there a way to separate regular expressions into substructures?

Tags: java, regex

Imagine 2 rules for a regular expression:
Rule A: string must consist of groups that abide by following rules, ... 
Rule B: each group made by rule A, must consist of sub groups that abide by following rules, ...

I would assume with complicated rules regular expressions would become extremely difficult to read even for the person who wrote them and they would often repeat themselves. Is there a way in java or in general to separate your Regular Expression patterns into substructures?

Comment: regex is basically a write-only language. you can't create "marcos" and reuse them. all you can do is try to use as much repetition as possible in your expression to shorten its length

Comment: Parenthesis can group elements, though this is mainly for returning the groups that are found.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to split up your regular expressions into substructures, I recommend creating an ArrayList of all of your regex pattern strings like so:

```
ArrayList<String> patterns = new ArrayList<String>();
patterns.add(pattern1);
patterns.add(pattern2);
// ...
patterns.add(patternN);
```

Then, you can pass that ArrayList along with the string that you plan to evaluate into a method like the one below:

```
public static boolean deepMatch(ArrayList<String> patterns, String text) {
    // TODO: Validate input here

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patterns.get(0));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    // Loop through each match
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (patterns.size()> 1) {
            // Pop first pattern
            patterns.remove(0);

            // Recursively check subgroups
            if (DeepMatch(patterns, matcher.group()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            // No more subgroups to go through
            return true;
        }
    }

    // No group met all pattern criteria
    return false;
}
```

This will search for matches to the first pattern in your ArrayList and then recursively search for matches to each subsequent pattern with each matched substring.

Comment: Solution looks interesting. But you should add some explanation to your code. Small hint: method names shouldn't start with capital letters ([coding conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)).

Comment: Tried to do that in the comments, but I'll add a broader description outside of the code. Haha, yeah I'm a C# developer primarily. Thanks for the tips. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found 1 solution, in Java, there is the split() method, it can split a string using a regex to identify an intersection and returns an array, it can also have a threshold of the amount of elements in the returned array, only checking for the regex n-1 times \

Here is a better explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/ 

In my example, if rule A separates groups by some intersection such as a hyphen, you can pass this as a string into the method and assign it to an array like so.

`String[] myArray = myString.split("-")` 
Then you can iterate over the array with another regex checking rule B. Hope this helps someone.